# Can anyone explain the bold sentance?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, synonyms, indian-english

They were perhaps four metres apart when the girl stumbled and fell almost flat on her face. **A sharp cry of pain was wrung out of her**. She must have fallen right on the injured arm

Comment: What is the problem that you have with this sentence. It uses figurative language, but it doesn't seem particularly difficult to parse.  Please edit to explain what you think it means. and what doubts you have about its meaning.

Comment: You have added tags for "grammar", "meaning" and "indian-english".  Are you asking about the grammar structure,  or the meaning of the phrase.  Why "Indian English"? Is this written in Indian dialect?

Comment: Please edit to explain what you think it means. and what doubts you have about its meaning.  You should use a dictionary to help you first.

Answer (score 2):

She made a sharp cry of pain in reaction to the fall.

The phrasing "a cry was wrung out of her" is poetic and emphasises it wasn't deliberate on her part but an involuntary reflex.